# Databricks - read table from Snowflake to Databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, azure-databricks

I've seen a few questions on Databricks to Snowflake but my question is how to get a table from Snowflake into Databricks.

What I've done so far:
Created a cluster and attached the cluster to my notebook (I'm using Python)

```
# Use secrets DBUtil to get Snowflake credentials.
user = dbutils.secrets.get("snowflake-user", "secret-user")
password = dbutils.secrets.get("snowflake-pw", "secret-pw")
sf_url = dbutils.secrets.get("snowflake-url", "secret-sf-url")

# snowflake connection options
options = {
  "sfUrl": sf_url,
  "sfUser": user,
  "sfPassword": password,
  "sfDatabase": "DEV",
  "sfSchema": "PUBLIC",
  "sfWarehouse": "DEV_WH"
}
```

then I tried to use spark.read to read the FBK_VIDEOS table in Snowflake:

```
# Read table from Snowflake.
df = spark.read.format("snowflake").options(**options).option("dbtable", "FBK_VIDEOS").load()
```

*I've also tried: option("dbtable", "SELECT * FROM FBK_VIDEOS").load()*

but I see the following error for `df`:

> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation
> error:

The Traceback shows this when expanded:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3339556253176158> in <module>
      1 # Read table from Snowflake.
----> 2 df = spark.read.format("snowflake").options(**options).option("dbtable", "FBK_VIDEOS").load()
      3 
      4 display(df)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    208             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    209         else:
--> 210             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    211 
    212     def json(self, path, schema=None, primitivesAsString=None, prefersDecimal=None,

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
```

Comment: What's the SQL compilation error code? And I don't see a *role* being used, is public enough to be able to read from that table?

Comment: Hey @Sergiu thanks for responding. It didn't show what the SQL compilation error was, that was the entire error message. BUT yes you're right, it was because role was missing, this helped me & answered my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering for completeness and for future users who might have a similar problem.

As answered in the comments: Snowflake uses a role-based access control system, so it is vitally important that the role being used has the necessary privileges. In this case, there is no `USE ROLE` shown in the code so whatever role was active when the query was run did not have sufficient privileges.